# How to check if audio samples have only noise or are silent?

Tags: preprocessing, audio-recognition

I have a wav file I want to split into frames in order to feed it into a machine learning model. The problem is that the audio has silence with some noise at some points.

My problem is that I do not want to include frames with no sound (or only noise) in my dataset.

One solution I believe is to use a model for speech recognition or something similar to do classification and see if a frame includes only silence or noise.

However, I am searching for a solution that will not rely on machine learning but mostly on signal processing techniques or some other pre-processing method.

So, how could I exclude these frames with only silence or noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should apply speech enhancement algorithms to remove noise from speech. Then, you should use VAD (Voice Activity Detector) to remove silence from speech.